# Does this notation mean what I intend?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I was looking at divisibility rules earlier today and noticed that several of them had the same form, i.e. truncating the last digit and then adding or subtracting a multiple of it to the truncation. I wanted to see if a general proof existed for any prime number, and I was able to come up with something! This is what I came up with when I tried to write out the result, but I'm not sure if it's clear or means exactly what I want:

For any prime number $p$, digit $b$, and $a\in\mathbb{Z}^+,\quad p \mid 10a+b \Leftrightarrow p \mid a\pm qb$ where $q=\min\{x\in\mathbb{Z}^+| \quad p\mid 10x\mp 1\}$.

What I mean is that $p\mid a+qb$ when $p\mid 10q-1$ and $p|a-qb$ when $p\mid 10q+1$, then I just want to take whichever $q$ is the smallest. Is the notation I used correct for that?

Comment: No, $p|(10a+b) \Leftrightarrow p|(a\pm qb)$ to me would mean the same as $p|(10a+b) \Leftrightarrow (p|(a+qb) \wedge p|(a-qb))$ (where $\wedge$ means "and").  Also, when using the divisibility sign $|$, I personally find it best to use parentheses when you're also using addition.

Comment: Also, using "where..." is meant to indicate that $q$ is a value fixed from the beginning.  If you want to make a claim about what the value $q$ is based on the divisibility relations you mention, then you should say "then $q=\min\{x\in \mathbb{Z}^+ \mid p|(10x \mp 1)\}$".

Comment: Thanks so much. Exactly the information I was looking for (and thanks for the info about where too)!

Comment: See http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/universaldivtest.pdf.

Comment: @danny Glad to help.  Hopefully someone else can speak up in case they disagree.  If any disagreements would exist, it would like be concerning the use of $\pm$, which seems to mean different things in different contexts.  For example, while I think it essentially stands for an "and" above, if someone said "$x^2=1$ implies $x=\pm 1$", I would instead take it to mean "$x^2=1$ implies either $x=1$ or $x=-1$".

Comment: @KCd That's pretty much my approach, and it's really handy to see how someone else has written it up!